# why allow multiple descriptions for each term in a `dl`?

Tags: html, html-lists, semantics

Semantically, what's the difference between

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term 1</dt>
    <dd>Description 1a</dd>
    <dt>Term 2</dt>
    <dd>Description 2a</dd>
    <dd>Description 2b</dd>
    <dd>Description 2c</dd>
</dl>
```

and

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term 1</dt>
    <dd>Description 1a<dd>
    <dt>Term 2</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li>Description 2a</li>
            <li>Description 2b</li>
            <li>Description 2c</li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML5 Draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) says that a `dl` contains "name-value" groups (a.k.a. term-description groups), with each group containing at least 1 term and at least 1 description.

> The values within a group are alternatives; multiple paragraphs forming part of the same value must all be given within the same `dd` element.

In the first block, **Term 2** can be described as *either* **Description 2a**, **Description 2b**, *or* **Description 2c**. There are three *alternative* descriptions for **Term 2**. An example would be different definitions of the same word (called a [homonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)).

In the second block, **Term 2** must be described using *exactly one* description: a (unordered) list that contains all three of **Description 2a**, **Description 2b**, *and* **Description 2c**. For example, a list of ingredients needed for a given recipe (where the `dt` element represents the recipe name).